# Is there any way to manage a note set in a cell in GAS?

Tags: google-chrome, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a gimmick to judge whether a cell has a note or not in Google Apps Script with Google Spread Sheet.

We can set note in a cell using `setNote` method. However, I don't know how to use the information about note.

For checkbox, it seems possible using `getDataValidation();` and `getCriteriaType();`, because checkbox is defined with criteriatype `CHECKBOX`

Is there any way to deal with a note set in a cell in GAS? In the first place, is note a explicitly defined object in GAS API?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `note` you are talking about belongs to the `Class Range` under `Spreadsheet` service.

There are a number of methods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) that will enable you to interact with the note. To summarize those methods, see usage below:

#### getNote:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("B2");
var result = range.getNote();  // returns string
```

#### getNotes:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
var results = range.getNotes(); // returns string 2D array
```

#### clearNote:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
range.clearNote(); // clears all notes in range and then returns range
```

#### setNote:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
cell.setNote("This is a note"); // sets note in range and then returns range
```

#### setNotes:

```
var notes = [
  ["it goes", "like this", "the fourth, the fifth"],
  ["the minor fall", "and the", "major lift"]
];
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2:D3");
cell.setNotes(notes); // set notes in range and then returns range
```

We have these methods for `note` however, notes are not treated as objects.

#### EDIT:

If you want to find which cells have note, this is one of the few approaches you can do:

```
function findCellsWithNotes() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var notes = range.getNotes();
  notes.forEach(function(row, i){
    row.forEach(function(cell, j){
      if(notes[i][j]){
        Logger.log("cell '" + sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).getA1Notation() + "' has a note '" + notes[i][j] + "'");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `getDataRange` only returns the range from `A1` to  last row/col cell where there is a value. If you have notes on blank cells outside your data range, it will not be included. (You won't be having an issue here if all your notes are on cells that have values. If you have blank cells with notes outside the data range, then use `getRange` and specify the range instead. Adjust offsets on variables `i` and `j` accordingly.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit sorry that there seems no exact way to identify which cell has a `note` or not. 
But I'll try to make the best use of these methods.

Comment: Hi @okina24, I have updated my answer to show how to get cells with notes.